# I have two types that should be semantically identical. Why is one resulting in an error while the other one gets accepted?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, decidable, recursive-type

Take the following TypeScript code (you can see it live at https://tsplay.dev/w1GYAm):

```
type Graph<T=any> = {
    A?: T,
    B?: T,
    C?: T,
};

type X<T extends Graph> = T['B'] | T['C'] | number;
type Y<T extends Graph> = [ T['A'], T['A'] ];

type Y1<T extends Graph> = [ T['A'], T['A'] ] | T['C'];
type Y2<T extends Graph> = Y<T> | T['C'];

type G1 = {
  A: X<G1>,
  B: Y1<G1>,
  C: number,
};

type G2 = {
  A: X<G2>,
  B: Y2<G2>,
  C: number,
};
```

`Y1` and `Y2` should be semantically identical, thus `G1` and `G2` should be identical too.

However I'm getting an error on `G1`, but no error in `G2`:

> 'A' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
> 'B' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

The error seems persistent: removing either `G1` or `G2` doesn't change the state of the other.

Why am I getting an error in `G1`, while `G2` is accepted?

Furthermore, is this a bug in TypeScript or expected behavior? Is Typescript expected to be undecidable for cyclic/recursive stuff?

Comment: If you have a circular type definition that isn't one of the few specific supported recursive approaches then all bets are off, mostly. It really depends on whether the type checker *defers* evaluation (which means it will work), or whether it eagerly evaluates it (which means it won't).  I wouldn't think this is a "bug" in TS (and if it is, it will likely be that the bug is the part where it *works* and not where it *breaks*, see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37426#issuecomment-600319042)). Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that answers everything I asked. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. I would have one small further followup question though: where can I find documentation about which ones are the "few specific supported recursive approaches"?